# Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I want to add google api in my popup.html but there is an error in cosole

```
Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

can someone help me please? in manifest i have added

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js; object-src 'self'",
```

but it does not work. please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: add this line in your manifest file 
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",`

Comment: There is a great video here for Manifest V3. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjH2INUPmF4&ab_channel=RustyZone

Comment: how about the verison 3 @Noobdev

Comment: This doesn't work, first it needs to be like this:
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/api.js 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
    },

Second, when you try to upload that on chrome, it would give the error:

'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" in directive 'script-src'.
Could not load manifest.

Comment: @AsaadMahmood did you find a way to work it around?